# Dynamic onclick call of html buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my javascript I have an array of 3 elements:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

How do I create 3 html buttons such that each button's onclick calls a function with parameter array[i].

for result i want to have:

```
<button onclick='function("one")'></button>
<button onclick='function("two")'></button>
<button onclick='function("three")'></button>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @Burki i have tried  jquery $("#id").append("<button onclick=......") but it looks awful, especially if i have a lot of parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline handler will give us troubles at times. For example by accessing current element using `this` inside the event handler. So here in this case, You can do it with `dataset` and `addEventListener`.

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
array.forEach(function(itm){
  var elem = document.createElement("button");
  elem.textContent = itm;
  elem.dataset.data = itm;
  elem.addEventListener("click", clickHandle, false);
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
});

function clickHandle(){
  alert(this.dataset.data); //will display "one"/"two"/"three" based on the element clicked.
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/76tuaour/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To get you running quick here is a quick fix to your existing code.

If you say the buttons will be in order then you can make use of the indexes of the button.

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]; 

function Myfunction(e){
  var index = $('.container button').index(e.target)
  alert(array[index]);  // now you have the value here, use it for your further stuff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<button onclick='Myfunction(event)'></button>
<button onclick='Myfunction(event)'></button>
<button onclick='Myfunction(event)'></button>
  </div>
```

---

If you are looking for a cleaner way then I would recommend not to use the `onclick` attribute to bind event and directly bind events using Jquery. Like below..

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];

$('.container button').on('click', function() {
  var index = $('.container button').index($(this));
  alert(array[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button ></button>
  <button ></button>
  <button ></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var btn_list;   //The buttons parent element
var your_func;  //callback function
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    btn = document.createElement('BUTTON'); //create element
    btn.onclick = function() //assign callback, with item
    {
        your_func(array[i]);
    };
    btn_list.appendChild(btn); //and add it to parent element
}
```

where of course, your callback function and your buttons parent element were defined before....

Comment: This won't work because of the [infamous loop issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)